# How to Open Multiple Xibs with the same method?

Tags: ios, swift

I have configured my UIView using Nib's .So, I just want to pass the name of nib in a method and it will open the particular ViewController.

For opening a particular UIView made with Xib, I have done it like this

```
 func presentMyViewControllerNib(){
  let controller = MyViewController(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: nil)
  let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
  let currentController = getCurrentViewController()
  currentController!.present(navigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

`getCurrentViewController` here is just fetching the viewcontroller displayed.

So, i just want a method like this `func presentGeneralisedNib(nibName:String)` in which I pass the name of my Xib.
I think it's not possible but if someone can help.

Comment: Your generic method won't know the specific UIViewController subclass of the view controller contained in the xib... I don't know if the xib-oading mechanism takes care of this and you can just call `UIViewController(nibName: theNibName, bundle: nil)` in your all-purpose method.

Comment: I mean, I'm not sure if it will instantiate the right class (could test it)...

Comment: @NicolasMiari It's not working